# How to click on a link and get its color?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, anchor

OK, so this sounds simple, using jquery's 'click' function.

The thing is I want the ORIGINAL color of the link NOT its hovered color - e.g. if the link is green with a hover state of orange, I wat to grab the GREEN color.

I've tried as best as I can and shown it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sVDYe/3/)

Anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT:** apologies, but as a number of eagle eyes have spotted (thanks to them for pointing it out) green is actually "rgb(0, 128, 0)", NOT rgb(0, 255, 0) as shown in my original fiddle.

Comment: `<a href="#" data-color="orange">my link</a>`

Comment: Green is `(0, 128, 0)` for me, by the way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Store it in [jQuery's `data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) object:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $(this).data('color', $(this).css('color') );
})
.click(function() {
    alert( $(this).data('color') );
});
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVDYe/4/

---

For better performance, I'd use [the static methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) in the loop. [They're much faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-method-vs-static):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    $.data(this, 'color', $.css(this, 'color') );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sVDYe/13/

Comment: Ooooooh, that's really clever!!  I searched everywhere for that for days and it beat me everytime - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach..

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/sVDYe/33/

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tmpLink =$(this).clone();
    tmpLink.appendTo($(this).parent());    
    var acolor = tmpLink.css("color");
    tmpLink.remove();

    if (acolor == 'rgb(255, 165, 0)') {
        alert('wrong color - its ORANGE =' + acolor);
    } else if (acolor == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
        alert('CORRECT color - its GREEN =' + acolor);
    }
});
```

As [pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217098/how-to-click-on-a-link-and-get-its-color/12217307#comment16366398_12217098) pointed out.. Green is `RGB(0,128,0)`

Comment: @JosephSilber What do you mean?

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work because CSS rules can be quite specific. For example, this fails in case the rule is `.container > a { color: ... }` because it doesn't match the clone.

Comment: The color of the link will be affected by the stylesheet, which makes it dependent on its ancestors (and possibly by its siblings).

Comment: @JosephSilber ahh I see what you mean.. thanks.. Check the updated post for the fixed version :) `tmpLink.appendTo($(this).parent());`

Comment: Still not bulletproof :) For example, consider a selector with `:first-child`.

Comment: @pimvdb damn.. that was a good one.. Thanks though.. this was interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

http://jsfiddle.net/dadviegas/hfHBh/

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the color change using Jquery instead of css and store it:

http://jsfiddle.net/sVDYe/20/

```
var hoverColor;

$("a").hover(function () {
  hoverColor = $(this).css("color");
  $(this).css("color", 'orange');
}, function () {
  $(this).css("color", 'green');
});

$("a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var acolor = hoverColor;
  if (acolor == 'rgb(255, 165, 0)') {
    alert('wrong color - its ORANGE =' + acolor);
  } else if (acolor == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)') {
    alert('CORRECT color - its GREEN =' + acolor);
  }
});
```

Also green is

> rgb(0, 128, 0)

Answer (score -1):

check this it will work for sure

```
<script>
    $("a").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("colorclass");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for - I'm trying to GET the color, not SET it or toggle it, but thank anyway.